# Cythonize ray actor class

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, ray, cythonize

I'm using Ray library and then I want to Cythonize my package.
While [there is a reference](https://docs.ray.io/en/releases-0.8.6/advanced.html#notes) of how to adapt regular remote function

```
some_cython_func = ray.remote(some_cython_module.some_cython_func)
```

it's not clear how to deal with Ray Actor (decorator on a class level)

```
@ray.remote
class MyService:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def run(self):
        ...
    def helper(self):
        ...
```

After being cythonized this code produces such an error

```
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/ray-test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/actor.py", line 538, in _remote
    meta.method_meta.methods.keys())
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/ray-test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 358, in export_actor_class
    "class": pickle.dumps(Class),
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/ray-test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 70, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/ray-test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 656, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <cyfunction MyService.__init__ at 0x7fc230367c80>: it's not the same object as app.my_service.__init__
```

How to rewrite/adapt existing working ray code to work with Cython?

`Python 3.7.9` / `ray==0.8.6`

Comment: Have you tried `MyService = ray.remote(some_cython_module.MyService)` (in a regular Python module)? It would seem the obvious analogy to their suggestion for a function?

Comment: @DavidW thanks, I've missed something really obvious to try first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, seems like a simple solution as

```
MyService = ray.remote(_MyService)
```

works without issue.

[Ref to the Ray source code](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/worker.py#L1772)